# lsnrctl: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

When I type lsnrctl from my command prompt the below error message is displayed:

```
oracle@Gaurav:~$ lsnrctl
bash: /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/bin/lsnrctl: 
cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Can anyone please provide me lsnrctl for oracle 12c, so that I could replace it?

Comment: Looks like you've somehow installed 64-bit Oracle on a 32-bit system. That's my guess

Comment: Oracle is not supported on Ubuntu, so I'm voting to close this question

Comment: My oracle is working fine  database get started  @phil ,you can close the question no issues ,but surely i ll make this work and let you know .

Comment: What says file -szL /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/bin/lsnrctl?

Comment: @PeterHorvath Please refrain from referring to other users as "evil", especially for pointing out factual observations.

Comment: @GauravSoni You have right and not Phil. Yes, Oracle can be installed on Ubuntu and everywhere, and it is up to you to solve them if a problem is coming. The only difference that on ubuntu you will have _maybe_ more problems. But Oracle is anyways very problematic.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, don't worry about the comments. Your question or problem is total valid.

Second, there is a comment about "ubuntu isn't supported so your question should be deleted" which isn't right. If ubuntu isn't "supported", that means you will have probably more problems if you try to install it, and Oracle won't help you. But Oracle never can be really easy installed (I am thinking some like so easy as typing as an `apt-get install oracle-11.2-server` or like, which is easy. Sucking with a monstrous and buggy java installer, which Oracle DB has, isn't easy), not for the so-named "supported" distributions/systems and not for the "unsupported" ones. Second, your problem is still a valid database administration problem, even if you use ubuntu or not.

About your problem: it is really clear. `lsnrctl` had to be runnable. This error message has the very clear meaning: your lsnrctl has an invalid binary format in your architecture. For example, you are trying to run a 64-bit binary on a 32-bit system. Or you try to run an i386 binary on a ia64 system. Or your lsnrctl binary is somehow damaged.

The command `file -szL /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/bin/lsnrctl` could make clear, which is the real problem, thus what is happened to your lsnrctl. But it is very probable, that simply you have a bad distribution installed, and so you need a reinstall, give a try to this command before.

Comment: thanks for such a positive words,i have succeded with installing and running db but  this is my issue ,i will try this comments once i get back to home ,thanks alot

Comment: :/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/bin/lsnrctl: Composite Document File V2 Document, No summary info

Comment: @GauravSoni It is total corrupt, it had to be a linux binary file and not a document!

Comment: is there any way to fix that ,otherwise please suggest any  linux where i can easily install oracle .I read about opensuse, because redhat and suse are paid ,so opensuse is the only option thanks alot

Comment: If you have luck, and only this binary is corrupt, maybe you could get this binary from another source. If not, then reinstall oracle.